Spark Structured Streaming job that reads from kafka isn't shown in kafka consumer groups
I have created a spark streaming job using pyspark that uses readStream to read from a kafka topic and the uses writeStream to writes into a table in Oracle database.
The job can successfully read data and write to oracle table in real-time, I have tried producing messages while running the spark streaming job and it was able to read it and write it to oracle table immediately.
My problem is I COULD NOT FIND the consumer group for my spark job that consumed from the kafka
topic. I looked for it using this command:
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server myserver --list
but nothing is there!! also it's not shown in kafka UI!!
here is the code for the spark job:
topic = ""
schema_registry_url = ""

streaming_df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "")\
        .option("subscribe", topic) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .option("partition", "0") \
        .option("groupIdPrefix", "IamTheConsumer")\
        .load()

parsed_df=streaming_df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

parsed_df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append")\
    .foreachBatch(SaveToOracle)\ ##there is a function for this that does its job correctly
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()




I was expecting to find the this consumer in kafka UI or in /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh but I didn't find anything about it. *Taking into consideration that it wrote the data in the destination table so the job consumed.

Try removing the partition argument. You can select and filter the partition later

@OneCricketeer removed it but still cannot see consumer in kafka-consumer-group.
do you believe this has to do with it? so if kafka source doesn't commit any offset it wouldn't be able to know about the spark consumer at all?
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#:~:text=enable.auto.commit%3A%20Kafka%20source%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20commit%20any%20offset.

Reason may be spark streaming job is configured with enable.auto.commit = false,check it once again.
If enable.auto.commit configuration property is false then even though you read messages still you cannot see your consumer in below list.
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server myserver --list
If enable.auto.commit = true then kafka will periodically receive the committed offsets from spark streaming job.

used this parameter and still same behavior, maybe I misspelled it, here is how I used it:
streaming_df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "").option("subscribe", topic).option("startingOffsets", "earliest").option("partition", "0").option("groupIdPrefix", "IamTheConsumer").option("enable.auto.commit","true").option("auto.commit.interval.ms","1").load() 
Also used it without auto.commit.interval.ms but still same behavior :((

Does this mean kafka doesn't commit any offset consumed by a spark streaming job?
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#:~:text=enable.auto.commit%3A%20Kafka%20source%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20commit%20any%20offset.

Normally consumer will tell Kafka till which offsets he has received messages by committing the offsets to Kafka from consumer.Try this.....remove groupIdPrefix and try setting kafka.group.id property...see if it works.

tried kafka.group.id instead of groupIdPrefix but still same behavior
